# Python Sum of nested list with str items

Tags: python, string, sum, nested-lists

Given:

```
[[[[[[[[['A']]]]],[[[[['B']]]]],['C'],[[[[['D']]]]]]
```

Or something like that. A complicated nested list.

How can I return either:

```
'ABCD' or ['ABCD']
```

Recursive function with `int` is simple enough due to the `sum` helper function, but I can't imagine how to do this with `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive method to return a single string

```
def joinValues(i):
    if isinstance(i, list):
        return ''.join(joinValues(j) for j in i)
    else:
        return i

>>> l = [[[[[[[[['A']]]]],[[[[['B']]]]],['C'],[[[[['D']]]]]]]]]
>>> joinValues(l)
'ABCD'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatten` function from [`compiler.ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#module-compiler.ast) module to flatten a nested list,and you can use `join()` to join your characters :

```
>>> l=[[[[[[[[['A']]]]],[[[[['B']]]]],['C'],[[[[['D']]]]]]]]]
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> flatten(l)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> ''.join(flatten(l))
'ABCD'
```

*Note* that as mentioned in comment this function has been removed from python3 instead you can use `itertools.chain` within a recursion function! or as a more various ways you can checkout the [duplicated question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)!

Comment: This has been removed in Python 3

Comment: @jamylak yep, fixed thanks for reminding!